# Fixing: JsonNode not of type ObjectNode (but com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode), cannot call withArray() on it?

Tags: java, json, jackson

While an array with-in an array is legal in json -

This is valid json - [`{ "id": [1, 2, { "a": [4, 5] }] }`](https://jsonformatter.org/9691cc)

But when I try to create an array within an array using jackson library - I am facing below error -

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonNode not of type
> ObjectNode (but com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode), cannot
> call withArray() on it    at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode.withArray(JsonNode.java:1107)

My code snippet is as below -

```
if (root.getNodeType().equals(JsonNodeType.ARRAY)) {
    if (currentElem.endsWith("[]")) {
        root = ((ArrayNode) root).withArray(currentElem.substring(0, currentElem.length() - 2)); //error line
        if (!((ArrayNode) root).has(value))
            ((ArrayNode) root).add(value);
    } else {
        ((ObjectNode) ((ArrayNode) root).addObject()).put(currentElem, value);
    }
}
```

Is this as expected or are there any work arounds for this(like get/create an array obj first and then add edit the retrieved array and add it back... etc and ).

I am using jackson `2.13.4`.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to do, to avoid possible misunderstandings could you specify which is your json input and what you expect as json output?

Comment: @dariosicily - i am **not** reading json. In the above code I am ***creating*** a JsonNode object from some input and conditions. Possible values for input `currentElem` are `customer`, `products[]`, `orders[]` etc. But they can be any thing random. Basically my convention is -  ending with `[]` (as in `products[]`) means `ArrayNode` otherwise `ObjectNode`.  ..cont...

Comment: ....cont...  And I have to create an `ArrayNode` inside an `ArrayNode` like `Orders Array` as `["address1", "address2",  {"date": Products[]}, {"date2" : Products[] }]` - thats where the above error is showing up. Data Relation is not so importation in the given example - just that kind of final structure is what I want.